# Simplest way to bind a ListViews ItemSource property to an ObservableCollection in the CodeBehind Class

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I'm trying to find the simplest and most elegant way to do a simple data-binding of a ListView to an ObservableCollection in .NET MAUI. Maybe I'm a little spoiled by web-development (Angular), where data-binding is just so easy and performant.

The best solutions I have found are the following:

1. XAML only approach.

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="..."
             x:Name="page"
             xmlns:services="..."
             Title="...">

  <ListView BindingContext="{x:Reference page}" ItemsSource="{Binding observableCollection}">
  </ListView>

</ContentPage>
```

I really like this approach, because I don't have to interact with the Markup Elements in the code-behind file. This is what I'd do in the other approach I have found.

XAML:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding observableCollection}"></ListView>
```

Code-Behind File:

```cs
public partial class ContentPage 
{
  // Edit: no need for a setter here
  public ObservableCollection<type> observableCollection { get; }

  public ContentPage()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    listView.BindingContext = this;
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a simpler or cleaner solution? Like where I can directly bind the ListViews ItemSource property to the ObservableCollection property of the code-behind class (like I'm used to do in web-development)?

Comment: Any element will inherit the BindingContext of the page.  There is no need to specify BindingContext on page elements unless they differ from the page itself

Comment: That must be false. The binding doesn't work if I omit setting the binding context of the list view to the ContentPage...

Comment: Also setter is not observable here.. So obviously listview will not notified about observableCollection change(it will notified about changes in collection but not on setting it) obvious solution is to implement inpc or use attached properties (I'm from WPF world not sure if they are things in maui)

Comment: You're right. I can just omit the `set` keyword. Doesn't make sense to have it here, I guess. Thanks or the hint.

Comment: You have to set the BindingContext for the page

Comment: I recommend using the [Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm) design pattern instead of adding business logic and data to the code behind.

Answer (score 2):

We generally recommend using [Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm).

You can refer to the following code:

1. create a ViewModelc class (e.g. `MyViewModel.cs`)

   ```
   public class MyViewModel {
       public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

       public MyViewModel() {
           Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

           Items.Add(new Item { NumType = "S", LocationCode = "0001" });
           Items.Add(new Item { NumType = "M", LocationCode = "0002" });
           Items.Add(new Item { NumType = "L", LocationCode = "0003" });
           Items.Add(new Item { NumType = "S", LocationCode = "0001" });
           Items.Add(new Item { NumType = "M", LocationCode = "0002" });
           Items.Add(new Item { NumType = "L", LocationCode = "0003" });

       }
   }

   public class Item {

       public string NumType { get; set; }

       public string LocationCode { get; set; }

   }
   ```
2. set the `BindingContext` for current page(`MainPage.xaml`) and set `ItemsSource` for the ListView.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 

   <ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiListViewApp"
             x:Class="MauiListViewApp.MainPage">

       <ContentPage.BindingContext>
            <local:MyViewModel></local:MyViewModel>
       </ContentPage.BindingContext>

       <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

           <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
               <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                       <TextCell Text="{Binding NumType}" 
                                 Detail="{Binding LocationCode}" />
                   </DataTemplate>
               </ListView.ItemTemplate>
           </ListView>

        </VerticalStackLayout>

    </ContentPage>
   ```